# Extremely hard and stimulating (undergraduate) real analysis $problems$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, soft-question

To put it simply: I have seen many problem books in *real analysis* (also on this website), but the exercises they propose seem quite standardized.

> What are problem books that propose really challenging and stimulating
>   ***problems*** (as opposed to standardized exercises)?

Comment: [Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis](http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Real-Analysis-Advanced-Calculus/dp/0387773789), maybe?

Comment: @Zircht The idea is something like that. Just a little bit more difficult.

Comment: What, to you, is the difference between a "problem" and an "exercise"?

Comment: [Problems and Theorems in Analysis I: Series, Integral Calculus, Theory of Functions](http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Theorems-Analysis-Functions-Mathematics/dp/3540636404) by Polya & Szego may be ?

Comment: @RamanaVenkata I knew that one. It's indeed the kind of book I'm searching for.

Comment: Though it's isolated, ever since I answered it, I've been curious about what happens if you give [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079402/eventually-constant-maps) to students. I found it fascinating and difficult, but amenable to fairly straightforwards techniques if one works at it for a good while. (Though I wouldn't pose it as a "Everyone should solve this!" because it would be immensely frustrating in that context)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the book "Selected problems in real analysis" by Makarov and 3 co-authors: [http://www.amazon.com/Selected-Problems-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821845594](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821845594)

This is a very beautiful book, and some of the problems are quite hard.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend G. H. Hardy, "A Course of Pure Mathematics", a classic with many challenging problems. http://ebookee.org/A-Course-of-Pure-Mathematics-Centenary-edition_731929.html

Answer (score 4):

Here are two suggestions:

-- A link to Vaughan Jones's RA course at Berkeley. In the introductory remarks he acknowledges the difficulty of the HW problems (links on the page)

https://math.berkeley.edu/~vfr/MATH10411/index.html

-- Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis," a great book in its own right, has over 500 problems, with many from Berkeley qualifiers.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387952977](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952977)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a list](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seeger/522/a.pdf) of undergrad level analysis problems intended to prepare you (in part) for an analysis graduate qualifying exam.

You can find lots of undergrad level problems in qualifying exams from many different departments. For instance, you can get [Wisconsin's here.](http://math.library.wisc.edu/reserve/qualifying-exams.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try "Problems in mathematical analysis" by Kaczor Nowak, AMS. This book has three volumes and you need them all.
For metric spaces I prefer http://www.amazon.in/Topology-Metric-Spaces-Second-S-Kumaresan/dp/8184870582 this book and http://www.springer.com/in/book/9781846283697

lastly for topology I prefer http://www.amazon.in/Topology-Munkres/dp/9332549532/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1495724772&sr=8-1&keywords=munkres+topology ,

[https://www.amazon.com/Topology-James-Dugundji/dp/B002OOA0VO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OOA0VO)

and http://www.amazon.in/INTRODUCTION-TOPOLOGY-MODERN-ANALYSIS-Simmons/dp/0070597847/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1495724849&sr=1-1&keywords=simmons+topology

lastly as an undergraduate student I should strongly recommend baby Rudin book(principles of mathematical analysis),this book's problems are really good! and everyone should try them.